# Stretching a button vertically in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm working on using a custom `ListView` that uses an inline delete button, but can't get the button to stretch vertically when the `ListView` row goes over 1 line.

I'm also having a bit of trouble with getting the text to respect the boundaries of the button, though that was working earlier so I suspect that to be an easy fix.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txt_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />

 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:background="@drawable/delete"
     android:contentDescription="@string/delete"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it comes out looking like so:

[image: My ListView]

Comment: What about `@drawable/delete`? It looks like an image (red rect with a X over), isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it's a 9patch drawable that I'm setting the background of the button to

Comment: Share the 9patch too please.

Comment: The 9patch works fine, I imagine if it was an issue with the 9patch it would have just resulted in an ugly button, but the 9patch is here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J4L71.png

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to bother you. I'd just want to use the same assets as you in my tests. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txt_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text=""/>

 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:contentDescription="@string/delete"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cripes, I can't believe it was as simple as using a LinearLayout instead of a Relative. All I had to do was change the 'layout_height' from your code to 'match_parent' and it's golden. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Add this property for button

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

The image view is stretching but the image it hold do not. Please change

```
android:background="@drawable/delete"
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/delete"
```

Comment: After this you'll have another issue of text going in background of the button. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set button is also

```
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"


<Button 
     android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:background="@drawable/delete"
     android:contentDescription="@string/delete"/>
```

I think it help you.